# Mern Stack Client Build Not Deployed On heroku

Tags: web, heroku, backend, web-deployment, mern

i try many times but can not find the problem need argent help please help anyone.when i deployed on heroku backend routes work but client build static not work

this is my github repo https://github.com/Tanvir-Niloy/Manobik_Narsingdi

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is mostly for making server side apis so you would connect it to your client side app to make it have server side.

Answer (score 0):

From your `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {      
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

You also have a `Procfile` with the content: `web: node server/server.js`

Without the `Procfile` Heroku would have executed `web: npm start` which is the same as `web: node server/server.js` anyway.

But as you can see from the `start` script you are not executing your client project. You are merely running the backend but you are not serving your static websites.

You either need to host your client project somewhere (GitHub has some solutions: GitHub pages, Netlify, Vercel, ...) or you need to serve your static content from your server project. You are kinda doing it but as of now you are continuously changing your code:

```
app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/static')))
```

To me it looks like you have a path issue here. Should be `'./../client/build/static'` assuming the build files are placed in the `client` folder.

Sharing the `build.log` would also help to see if your project builds properly on Heroku.

Comment: please add on my github repo so you can easily  find and solve the problem